# MySQL query doesn't work with sorcerer in Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I've installed sorcerer in Joomla! 3.2 to execute some custom php.

The basic php code works fine, but the SQL-query gives no result. My code:

```
{source}

$servername = //my db-server;
$dbname = //my db-name;
$username = my db-username;
$password = my db-password;
$connection = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM workshops";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis)) {
  echo $row->id;
}

{/source}
```

At a normal website without joomla! that code works perfect.

**edit:**

the correct query would look like this:

```
{source}

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'workshop_title', 'workshop_time');
$query->from($db->quoteName('workshops'));
$query->order('ordering ASC');

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

echo $results->id;

{/source}
```

Comment: What is shown in `error.log` ?

Comment: This is really a bad approach to do things.

Comment: See the following resource as a place to start:: http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla has a class for that, read more about it at with really nice examples on how to set it up http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: Link-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they may break in the future.  Answers should contain the solution as a hardcoded component of the answer.